# jQuery $this is not working on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry but i am newbie!!!
i am new to jQuery and i have a problem with jQuery $(this)

i have create a really simple jquery function in jsfiddle and it work but it's not work on website

i have use jquery 1.10.1 in jsfiddle and my code too!

you can see code here :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".resumeActu").on('click', function(){
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                alert("id is = "+id);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="resumeActu" data-id="3">click me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my code in jsfiddle too: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7VyNe/)

i cant understand why my code work on jsfiddle but it's not work in my page

Comment: is your website live ?

Comment: Its working http://jsfiddle.net/7VyNe/1/. Change your jQuery version. You are using very old jQuery version for JSFIddle

Comment: no it's in my localhost but if you want i can upload it somewhere but they are really same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your website you need to place your code in a document ready handler. This is not required in jsFiddle as it automatically does it for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".resumeActu").on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            alert("id is = "+id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The reason your current code does not work is because it is trying to attach the click handler to the `.resumeActu` element before it exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resumeActu").on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        alert("id is = " + id);
    });
});
```

Load this function after document is ready